# Average number of tries to reach 5 successes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So, I have a somewhat non-trivial probability question. The situation is as follows:

> You start off with 5 blank spots in order. In order to fill this spot, you flip a coin/any other event with a 50% chance of success (i.e. heads). If you're successful, you fill in the first blank. You flip the coin again. It lands on tails, so you go back to 0 blanks. The idea is, for every success you fill in a blank, for every failure you remove an existing success.
>
> Note: THE FIRST COIN (That is 0 successes to 1 success is ALWAYS
> successful). The rest are at 50%.

My question is: *How would I find the average number of tries I need to fill in all 5 blanks.*

Edit: First blank that is filled in is at $1$ probability, not $0.5$.
Edit: The lowest it goes is 0 successes, you don't go into negative filled land.

Comment: Your note confuses me. Should we count the $0.5$ probability from first coin or not?

Comment: What happens if after the initial so-called success, we have failure failure? Are we in negative filled land?

Comment: @Alistair The first coin, filling in the first blank that is at $1$ probability.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, the lowest it goes is 0.

Comment: I've edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(n)$ be the expected number of remaining flips when $n$ of the spots are filled in.  For $1 \le n \le 4$, we have $$X(n) = 1 + \frac12(X(n-1) + X(n+1))$$ 
because we need at least one flip plus whatever else we expect to need when we find ourselves with either $n-1$ or $n+1$ spots filled in.

$0$ and $5$ spots are exceptions to this pattern. Clearly, $X(5) = 0$. And a failed flip when $n=0$ leaves us in the $n=0$ state, so $X(0) = 1 + \frac12(X(0) + X(1))$.

We now have six simple linear equations in the six unknowns $X(0), \ldots, X(5)$.  Solving these, we obtain: $$\begin{align}
X(0) & = 30 \\
X(1) & = 28 \\
X(2) & = 24 \\
X(3) & = 18 \\
X(4) & = 10 \\
X(5) & = 0
\end{align}
$$

so the final answer is that the expected number of flips, counting the initial success, is $X(1)+1 = 29$.  Computer simulations confirm this answer.

Comment: Good answer, though 'And a failed flip when n=0' is wrong, you may have not seen the edit, but if n=0, the flip always succeeds.

Comment: You said “THE FIRST COIN”, and I took you at your word; my calculation assumes only that THE FIRST COIN is always successful; after that the coin comes up heads or tails with equal probability.  Feel free to adjust the $X(0)$ equation to $X(0) = 1 + X(1)$ and solve the resulting system to obtain the answer you want.

Comment: Well I apologize for the misunderstanding then. Thank you.